# How to make Wildfly 10.1.0 work in port 80 and 443 (SSL) with h2 (HTTP/2) protocol in Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redirect, wildfly, http2

I'm trying to make the wildfly work on ubuntu in production.

I was able to make it work with its standard **8080** and **8443** ports, and managed to redirect ports **80** to **8080** and **443** to **8443** using iptables from ubuntu.

But when performing this redirection, the page opens in https but the **h2** protocol (HTTP / 2) and **gzip** do not work.
If I go direct in the standard wildfly protocol (**www.example.com:8443**) **gzip** and **h2** work perfectly.

Here is the iptables redirect command:

> Iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -dport 80 -j REDIRECT
>   --to-port 8080
>
> Iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -dport 443 -j REDIRECT
>   --to-port 8443

I've tried using nginx to do the redirect and the same problem happens.
I also tried configuring wildfly to use port **80** and **443** directly but **Ubuntu does not allow it**.

I have the following status in firewall:
[ufw status verbose of server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lppo.png)

If there is a way to make the wildfly in port **80** and **443** or make the redirect work in **h2** and **gzip**.

**System:**

- Ubuntu :  16.04.1
- Wildfly : 10.1.0.Final

Please help me solve this problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution.
The problem is in my Windows 10 Anti-Virus (More specifically BitDefender 2017).

All the tests I did was on a Windows 10 operating system, by the time I switched to Linux (I have dual boot) the site finally got http2 
So I saw that the name of the issuer of the certificate that was being used was: Bitdefender Personal CA.Net-Defender.

It was at this point that I realized that my certificate created by letsencrypt was being overwritten by another bitdefender certificate.

**SOLUTION:** In BitDefender enter the module settings, and go to the internet module and disable the option to verify SSL certificates. Restart your browser and you're done.

So beware when testing a website using an antivirus.